# Pandas dataframe row, divide the row elements with a fixed float value, Dataframe has only one row

Tags: python-3.x

QTY 1   QTY 2   QTY 3   QTY 4   QTY 5   QTY 6   QTY 7   QTY 8   QTY 9   QTY 10  QTY 11  QTY 12  QTY 13  QTY 14  QTY 15  QTY 16  QTY 17  QTY 18  QTY 19  QTY 20  REV Price
28  39  41  44  33  33  44  36  41  46  29  34  35  31  28  38  31  36  45  30  250 25

I have only one in a pandas Data frame which 22 columns
I want to divide all the columns that starts with QTY with "mean_val" which is equivalent to  25.3654
How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, lets say your dataframe is in variable df :

```
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith('QTY')] /= mean_val
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
# Sample data frame defined as per your requirement and the mean value.
data = { 'qty 1': [23] , 'qty 2': [26], 'price': [25], 'rate': [250]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=None)
mean_value = 25.3654

# Using dataframe's update() and filter() functions to achieve the outcome
df.update(df.filter(regex='qty.*') / mean_value)
print(df)
```